# Running Stored Procs on Different Databases through Agent Job

Tags: sql-server

I have a list of three stored procedures that need to be ran daily on a number of separate SQL databases. Each database is named differently, but the stored procedures on each are the same.

I have extremely limited knowledge on anything other than basic queries, but was thinking I could have a SQL Server Agent job on a database I set up as Master. Then I have that server push that job to the other databases once I configure those as Targets. My issue is that in thinking through this, the database names are different and within the SQL Server Agent wizard I can only set the database to what's currently on master instance.

What would be the best approach to executing this looping through servers to run the stored procs?

Comment: Do you mean different SQL Server instances (could be on the same physical server or different machines) and not just different databases that all exist under the same service instance?

Comment: They are different SQL Server instances.

Comment: Do you have all these instances listed as linked servers to the one that you are treating as the Master? If so, you could look into using OPENQUERY to do the remote execution.

Comment: They are not linked, but it looks like that is the best route to go. I had heard of OPENROWSET but that would require Ad Hoc queries to be allowed and that doesn't seem appropriate. I've also heard SSIS, but I know nothing of it to know where to being with SSIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is a linked-server. They allow servers to be linked so that you can call objects from one server to another. They are very easy to setup. In your case, you'll need to create 3 linked-servers on the main server, which will be used to schedule the job. A linked-server will allow the main server to link to listed servers. [Here are tutorials of how you can create a linked-server.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560998.aspx)

Once you've created a linked-server you'll simply create a job that will execute all 3 sprocs, something like this:

```
EXEC [server1].[database].[schema].[sp_name];
EXEC [server2].[database].[schema].[sp_name];
EXEC [server3].[database].[schema].[sp_name];
```